# GSON deserialize/serialize hierarchy class

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a java app that send json content to my server (c++). I my server i receive the json, do the parse, the validation, etc and send back the response with json too.
I have one request in my java app that have this json body (example):

```
{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "searchMethod": {
        "searchByUser": {
            "userId": "userId"
        }
    }
}
```

But for the same command i can have other `searchMethod`:

```
{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "searchMethod": {
        "searchByEmail": {
            "email": "user@user.com"
        }
    }
}
```

So, when the user do the request we can send to my server one of this two different json bodys. I never know what `searchMethod` we send. This part (check what searchMethod the user send, etc), i do in my c++ server when i receive the json. So in my java app i only need to use the gson to send a `searchMethod` object with their content.

This my class to do the request:

```
public class RequestExample implements SerializableJSON
{
    public String a;
    public String b;

    public RequestExample(String a, b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static RequestExample fromStringJson(String data)
    {
        try
        {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.fromJson(data, RequestExample.class);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static RequestExample fromBytesJson(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null) return null;
        try 
        {
            String str = new String(data, "utf-8");
            return fromStringJson(str); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toJsonString()
    {
        try
        {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.toJson(this);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] toJsonBytes()
    {
        try 
        {
            return this.toJsonString().getBytes("utf-8");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I already implement the fields `a` and `b` because its always the same in this request. In this class the `fromStringJson(String data)` receive the data string field that contain all json that the user try to send. In this function i use the `gson.fromJson` to convert this string to a json object type of my `RequestExample` class.

So the main question is: How to adapt my `RequestExample` class to convert the string to a json object regardless of the type of `searchMethod`. Like i said in my java app i dont need to know how `seachMethod` the user choose. In my server yes, but this part i already implement. So for now, i only need to send the request to my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use field `searchMethod`, you can implement it like a `Map`

```
private Map<String, Object> searchMethod = new HashMap<>();

or

private Map<String, Map<String,Object>> searchMethod = new HashMap<>();

or

private Map<String, Map<String,String>> searchMethod = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand your code but i have one doubt. What is the object? searchByUser or searchByEmail? In this map i need to define some object ok but i dont know that type of object the user choose. Do you understand my doubt? The same command can have searchByUser or searchByEmail.. when i receive my string data i dont know what searchMethod the user put

Comment: Sorry. I dont need user java hiearchy. I can use only a map like this:
Map <String, Map<String, String>> searchMethod, because the valdiation about the json content i do in my server. With this way i can send the searchMethod and inside c++ server i parse the json and do the validations :)

Comment: As I understood, you found solution, so I edited answer for other people

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your help ;)